# I always get these errors when installing electron?

Tags: node.js, electron

[image]

I always get these errors - I tried (npm install electron) and (npm install electron-prebuilt) , both give me the same errors
my OS : windows 7 and I have the latest version of nodeJS (7.7.1)

Comment: Can you try npm install electron --verbose and see if you get more information about the error?

Comment: I also tried to install it globally (-g) , same errors

Comment: the screen load tons of lines , too many lines , I can't detect the problem

Comment: with the --verbose load a tons of lines right? If yes, paste in some Gist or another website and share with us.

Comment: Sort of obvious - but are you able to install other npm packages?

Comment: same errors -_-

Comment: @NoGrabbing Yes , I installed ionic and cordova before without any issue

Comment: @AhmedMohsen can you share the --verbose log with us? Do a Gist, or public Drive link, if possible.